# Data selectors for jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using `.delegate()`, which requires a selector as its first argument.

I would like the selector to select all element on the page that have `data('myData') === true`.

Do such selectors exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you could [create such](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/a-better-data-selector-for-jquery/).